# Excel VBA extract substring based on InStr and paste into worksheet2 loop for all cells in column

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

Microsoft Excel VBA

I have a list of strings containing shop ID codes & address combined in column Y, and I want to go down this list, extract just the ID code, and paste this into a second spreadsheet in column C.

I am struggling with how to use a For statement to loop this for each cell in the columns, as I want the statement to find the info from a cell in Activesheet column Y, then paste the substring into Sheet Part 1 Column C, and then loop to the next cell in the range for both sheets.

My insufficient code:

set up a for loop for the Y column in ActiveSheet, where the shop ID info is stored

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("Y:Y")
```

create a location variable to store the instr value, should change each loop, not sure if this is the way to do it however

```
    Dim location As Integer
```

create an object that stores where the ID code finishes in my string

```
    location = InStr(1, ActiveSheets.Range("Y:Y"), " ")-1
```

using the left function with the location object, tell excel I want to copy the shop ID and paste it into column C in the Part 1 Sheet.

```
    Left(xCell, location).Copy Sheets("Part 1").Range("C:C")

Next
```

Full Code without annotations:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("Y:Y")
    Dim location As Integer
    location = InStr(1, ActiveSheets.Range("Y:Y"), " ")-1
    Left(xCell, location).Copy Sheets("Part 1").Range("C:C")
Next
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Location as long
Dim c as range
For each c in range("Y:Y")
    Location = instr(" ",trim(c.text))
    if location >0 then
        sheets("Part 1").range("C" & c.row).value = left(c,location)
    end if
 next c
```

This assumes that you want them to appear in column C in the same row as they are in in column Y

Edit to fix my error and to add a trim - I suspect you have a leading space in column Y?

Comment: Thanks for the code.
Currently, it's bugging when I use.text in the 6th line, but works for .Value.
It's also not returning any values, when I use the line break on line 6, I can see that the value of the Location variable never goes above 1. It should be between 6 and 9. Any further ideas would be amazing.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the update, there was no leading space in column Y and the location variable is still always 1. Annoyingly, in my half completed code, the location was changing correctly for each row. Cheers again!

Comment: That's cos I'm an idiot! Location = instr(" ",trim(c.text)) should be location = instr(" ",c.text)  I got them the wrong way round!